Unpaarametered Mediation paths SEM with same degree of freedom comparison
I am modelling multilevel mediation paths for my data. The idea is that a1,a2,b1, b2, c1, c2,d1,d2 all contribute to outcome variable y, and b-level, c-level, and d-level variables also affect y through affecting a-level variables, and c-level, d-level vars  also affect y through affected b-level to affect a-level variables, so on and so forth. I am using lavaan in R, following is my current code:
model1 <- "
y ~ a1 + a2 + b1 + b2 + c1 + c2 + d1 + d2
"

model2 <- "
y ~ a1 + a2 + b1 + b2 + c1 + c2 + d1 + d2
a1 ~ b1 + b2 + c1 + c2 + d1 + d2
a2 ~ b1 + b2 + c1 + c2 + d1 + d2 "

model3 <- "
y ~ a1 + a2 + b1 + b2 + c1 + c2 + d1 + d2
a1 ~ b1 + b2 + c1 + c2 + d1 + d2
a2 ~ b1 + b2 + c1 + c2 + d1 + d2 
b1 ~ c1 + c2 + d1 + d2
b2 ~ c1 + c2 + d1 + d2
"
...
...

I have two questions.

is my syntax making sense or are they doing what I specified in my text? As I can see in tradiational mediation paths models, people would specify parameters like
y ~ a*x1 + b*x2 etc. but that would add so much complexity to my model and I'm not sure how to approach that in my multilayer models.
the model summary did suggest I have more parameters along further layers, but the degree of freedom stayed the same except for the basline (multiple linear regression) model. Is that because I have nested models?
If my syntax is doing the "correct job", how should I compare the models to see if additional mediation paths are benefitting the model? I tried doing anova() between each level with the baseline level, as I can't use anova() between mediation layers due to same df.

I would really appreciate any suggestions.
